# Can we rewrite $\prod \frac{e^{y_i}}{y_i}$ in any way?

Tags: calculus, optimization, semidefinite-programming

I'm working out an optimization problem, and I want to find the minimal value of $$\prod  \frac{e^{y_i}}{y_i}$$

How do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem sounds too generalised.
I am not a pro at optimisation problems,but i think for finding a solution you have to define atleast some parameters like

1. the vector of y<sub>i</sub> on which you are optimising
2. any discrete/continious function which defines the set of y<sub>i</sub>,if so define the interval of y<sub>i</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Is there any condition on $y_i$?
If no, then $y_i\to 0$ makes the expression tend to infinity, so there is no minimum on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I found out letting $y_i \to 0$ tends to $e$ using L\hopitals rule, which is the minimum.

Comment: Be careful. What is $i$ and what is the range of $i$?